# visual Studio 2010: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I built a project in visual studio 2010 using c and got a DLL and was trying to use the DLL in postgresql 9.2. but i am getting this error:
ERROR:  could not load library "C:\projmpt.dll": The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.
I installed the latest version of Visual C++ Redistributable Packages but still not working.anyone who has any idea about this problem?

Comment: Is projmpt.dll the DLL you are trying to use?

Comment: That's an error that's typically generated by older versions of the runtime DLLs.  So installing the "latest version" isn't going to fix it.  Look in the Windows application event log for the details.  High odds that you ought to rebuild the DLL.

Comment: Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can help you with the dependencies.